# Grails GSP tag to submit form with link?

Tags: grails, gsp

I'd like to submit a form using a link instead of a submit input.  Is there a tag in Grails that does this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is a tag that allows multiple submit buttons within a form, if thats the issue??? Also links to a specific action. http://grails.org/doc/1.2.0/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want it to generate a `<input type="button"/>` -- I want it to generate an `<a href="#" onclick=".."/>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a GSP tag for this. You might have to produce your own custom tag lib.

http://grails.org/doc/1.2.0/guide/single.html#6.3 Tag Libraries

Or, just code the html input yourself

Comment: Yeah, I've gone the straight html input route, and just have an onclick that grabs the form and submits.